# Sqlite3 window frame partition by datetime not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm struggling with a window frame coding with Python's sqlite3. Basic I have this dataframe:

[image]

And I want to group all the clients (buy and sell) made in the same day and week.
I'm working with the follow sqlite3 code:

```
pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', execution_time) AS dia,
                            COUNT(customer_id) AS cons_dia,
                            SUM(cons_dia) OVER
                                PARTITION BY dia
                                ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS seven_day
                        FROM trades
                        ORDER BY dia DESC;""", conn)
```

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, it says there is a problem around "dia" (I think it means the line `PARTITION BY dia`. Sqlite3 does not recognize daytime, that's why I need to to the `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', execution_time)` in the first row.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derived columns `cons_dia` and `dia` can't be used in the same `SELECT` statement.
Instead you should use the expressions from which they are derived:

```
SELECT date(execution_time) AS dia,
       COUNT(customer_id) AS cons_dia,
       SUM(COUNT(customer_id)) OVER (
         ORDER BY date(execution_time)
         ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS seven_day
FROM trades
GROUP BY dia
ORDER BY dia DESC;
```

Note that you need an `ORDER BY` clause inside the `OVER()` clause of the `SUM()` window function and not a `PARTITION BY` clause, which should be extended to 6 rows before the current row if you want a 7 day window.
Also, this will work only if there are no gaps between the dates in the table.

Comment: Hello again @forpas I understood what you mean, but this coding is still returning the same values in cons_dia and seven_day . Do you know why it could be?
Do you think it might be the group_by?

Comment: @jvqp see my edited query.